# How to mange components outside render function?

Tags: react-native, styles, mapping, rendering

I am building Mushaf App for Quran. I did everything but I am facing some challenges and looking for some help

**First one** I have to map through JSON response to show the text like book so if I map it outside the render function I will not be able to manage the styling of text while inside the render function it comes like list not like book text ( I mean coming line by line ). So how to get it done inside the render function so I can control it's styling and if I add all my logic inside the function itself I am getting this error `Cannot Add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent with out a measure function`

**Second one** I am navigation user for the page number through Surah list then how to make it easy to change Surah list by sweeping or even with some ease row so the user can navigate through pages freely

**Third one** I can not make the text fully justified in the page

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, 
        Text, 
        StyleSheet, 
        TouchableOpacity, 
        ImageBackground, 
        Dimensions,
        Image
    } from 'react-native';
import QuranApi from '../API/QuranApi';
import {Audio} from 'expo-av';
import Uthmani from '../Fonts/Uthmani';
import { ArabicNumbers } from 'react-native-arabic-numbers';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const QuranShowScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [quran, setQuran] = useState([]);
    const page = navigation.getParam('page');
    const name = navigation.getParam('name');

   useEffect(() => {
     Quran();
   }, []);
    const sound = new Audio.Sound();


    const Quran = async () => {
        const response = await QuranApi.get(`/${page}/quran-uthmani`);
        setQuran(response.data.data.ayahs);
   }

      const text =  quran.map((t) => {

        return (
            <Text
            onPress = {async () => {
                await sound.loadAsync({
                    uri : `https://cdn.alquran.cloud/media/audio/ayah/ar.alafasy/${t.number}`
                });
                await sound.playAsync();
               }}
               onLongPress = {async () => {
                await sound.unloadAsync();
               }}
                key = {t.text}
            >
            {
                t.text.includes(`بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ`) ? 

                `
                 بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ                       
${t.text.replace('بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ', '')}` : `${t.text.replace('بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ', '')} ﴿${ArabicNumbers(t.numberInSurah)}﴾ `
            }
             </Text>
        )
    })


    return (
        <View style = {{marginHorizontal : 25}}>
        <View style = {styles.container}>        
        <Uthmani text = {text} />

        </View>
        </View>

    );
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        marginTop : 15,    
        marginHorizontal : 15,
        flex : 1,
        alignContent : 'center'
    },


     textStyle : {
 fontFamily : 'Uthmani',
          fontSize : 21,
          textAlign : 'justify',
          alignSelf : 'center',
          lineHeight :
        }
    });



export default QuranShowScreen;
```

[image: Screen shot for the output]

Comment: "if I map it outside the render function I will not be able to manage the styling of text"
Why? You can add style wherever you add it.

Comment: Yes I know. I mean it's not applicable to add two Text components without View which is not applicable

Comment: For your third point, I wrap my Arabic text with the following 
<p align="justify" style="direction: rtl !important;">
...
Arabic text
...
</p>